# Python for loop until index

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list containing 10000 images. I want to show the 1st 10 images. How do I write the for loop in Python ?

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('<my_directory>*.pgm'):
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(10):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_list[i])
```

That's my code. I have tried image_list(3), image_list(1:3) but it all doesn't work.

Comment: Slice up till 10: `image_list[:10]`

Comment: It still doesnt work. This is my code

Answer (score 0):

Slice the list

```
for ima in image_list[:10]:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(ima)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to show the first 10 images sorted by its name. If so try as below:

```
for ima in sorted(image_list)[:10]:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(ima)
```

Sample Result:

```
>>> image_list = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img0.jpg']
>>> image_list
['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img0.jpg']
>>> sorted(image_list)
['img0.jpg', 'img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']
>>> for img in sorted(image_list)[:1]:
...  print img
...
img0.jpg
```